# How can I get JAXB to generate empty tags for elements with restrictions?

Tags: java, jaxb, tags, schema, marshalling

I've been reading up how to get JAXB to generate empty element tags when marshalling (i.e. `<name/>`) and it seems as if I need to specify an empty string "". My schema has restrictions on some elements that require at least 1 character if the element is specified.

How can I get JAXB to generate the empty element tags without throwing validation errors on the restrictions?

***EDIT:***

Updated information - I have an element `name` that is referenced as part of a sequence in my XSD. This element is required in the sequence as it does not have an atrribute of `minOccurs="0"`. Unfortunately I have no control to change the XSD, so I cannot add the attribute.

When I enter an empty string `""` so that jaxb creates the empty element, I get a validation error because the name element has a restriction of `<xs:minLength value="1"/>` I want to be able to validate the XML to check for other issues, but skip this particular validation.

Comment: `<name/>` and `<name></name>` mean the same thing, which is an empty string, as opposed to the lack of a value. If your constraints are `minOccurs="0"` and disallow empty string, then `<name/>` is invalid, but missing `name` tag is valid, so why would you expressly want that generated? It violates the schema!

Comment: I'm getting neither `</name>` nor `<name></name>` it just doesn't print the tag at all. The problem is that the element is specified as `<xs:element ref="name"/>` so the sequence requires the tag, but the name element has the restrictions of minLength "1" and maxLength "255"

The client doesn't want a name specified in that tag which is why I just need an empty tag so i don't get a sequence error.

Comment: So if the element is required, and the length must be 1-256, then an empty string is *invalid*, and your code setting the value to `null` or `""` is violating the constraints, and should fail validation. Not having the tag is a sequence error. Having an empty tag is a length constraint error. Both are *invalid*.

Comment: We're adapting this application and using the schema that the client has given us. There was an old application that used this schema, created the XML with the empty name tag, and the client considers that valid XML. I cannot contact the old team on what they did and the client expects the schema to work since it did with the original application. Is there a way to set empty tags and avoid that particular validation?

Comment: Schema didn't work with the old application, it just wasn't being validated. Stop validating or change the schema.

Comment: This isn't exactly the solution I'm asking for, there must be some work around to exclude specific validations or add empty tags.

Comment: No. Either you validate to the schema and data has to be valid, or you don't validate. I guess you could validate and ignore errors, but then why validate in the first place? --- To exclude specific validations, remove them from the schema, aka "change the schema".

Comment: Validation would be done to catch errors not specifically related to this scenario. Unless you can tell me the solution I'm looking for specifically, I don't see the need to continue discussing why I need it.

Comment: Ok. Good luck waiting for a solution that doesn't exist. I've given my two cents for how to fix your problem.

Comment: You could be more specific on your use case and your xsd. Beside that you **might try**   [@XmlAdapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html). Keep us posted.

Comment: Updated with the solution I found. Another guy on my team suggested looking into XML Adapter as well, but I found this alternate solution that seemed better suited for this. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to work around and ignore specific validations. I created an   an event handler that implemented ValdationEventHandler for my JAXB code that looks like this:

```
public class MyEventHandler implements ValidationEventHandler {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyEventHandler.class);

@Override
public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {

    if(event.getLocator().getObject() instanceof com.path.MyObject || 
            event.getMessage().contains("length = '0' is not facet-valid with respect to minLength '1' for type '#AnonType_name'")){
        return true;
    }
    logger.info("\nEVENT");
    logger.info("SEVERITY: " + event.getSeverity());
    logger.info("MESSAGE: " + event.getMessage());
    logger.info("LINKED EXCEPTION: " + event.getLinkedException());
    logger.info("LOCATOR");
    logger.info(" LINE NUMBER: " + event.getLocator().getLineNumber());
    logger.info(" COLUMN NUMBER: " + event.getLocator().getColumnNumber());
    logger.info(" OFFSET: " + event.getLocator().getOffset());
    logger.info(" OBJECT: " + event.getLocator().getObject());
    logger.info(" NODE: " + event.getLocator().getNode());
    logger.info(" URL: " + event.getLocator().getURL());
    return false;
}
```

In the class with the JAXB Marshaller I added the event handler like this:

```
jaxbMarshaller.setEventHandler(new MyEventHandler());
```

When there is a validation event, it goes into the event handler, checks if it's the correct object and correct error on that object, if so it returns true which tells the marshaller to continue. If it's not this error, it will print out all the information about the event and return false so the marshalling fails.